# Dealing with UIImagePickerController to minimize memory useage

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

So, I have read the SO post on [UIImagePickerController, UIImage, Memory and More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more), and I read the post on [Memory Leak Problems with UIImagePickerController in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189707/memory-leak-problems-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-iphone). I have VASTLY increased my memory efficiency between these 2 posts, and I thank the OPs and the people that provided the answers.

I just had a question on the answer provided in the Memory Leak question, which was (essentially):

> only have one instance of the controller throughout the programs runtime

What would be the best way to go about this without causing memory leaks? Right now I am initiating it and releasing it on every use from within the view, and I am seeing exactly what the answer describes (Memory warnings and a crash after about 20 uses). Should I initiate the `UIImagePickerController` when I need it, but use a seperate class unrelated to the view to control it? How should I deal with releasing the controller if I do it this way?

## --EDIT--

As per the answer, the leak was fixed. My crashes must be coming from poor memory management. Posted a new SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041781/saving-uiimagepickercontroller-images-to-core-data-without-crashing) to account for the new question topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick it in your application delegate.

I'm pretty sure this leak was fixed in OS 3 though.

Comment: If the leak was fixed, does Apple still want it treated as a singleton?

Comment: The application delegate should NOT be used for these types of things. Yes, it's convenient, but it's not the intended purpose of that object. If you need to hold on to a singleton instance of UIImagePickerController, the recommended way to do so is to just create a class that follows the Cocoa Singleton design pattern (check the Cocoa documentation) and encapsulates a UIImagePickerController.